# How to animate fbx model using xna programmatically

Tags: animation, xna, 3dsmax, fbx

I have fbx model exported from 3ds max. I have 3d coordinate that are extracted from a motion capture session. I want to animate the model using these 3d coordinates. after googling I found xna can be used for this purpose.

I found a tutorial on [digitalrun](http://www.digitalrune.com/Support/Blog/tabid/719/EntryId/152/Real-Time-Motion-Capture-using-Kinect-and-XNA.aspx) that used kinectxna to capture motion and animate .fbx model using xna. but I can't build it because it wants kinect hardware elements.

I found another tutorial [here](http://blog.nuclex-games.com/tutorials/graphics/mesh-based-bone-animation/). I am newbie to xna. I faced difficulties to understand that.can someone point me to right tutorial that expalins skeletal animation of .fbx model using xna?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start with this example to understand how animation work:
http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-us/education/catalog/sample/skinned_model

The animation data is contained in the model itself. But you can change some code to work with your 3d coordinates.

Also...
I found a library to animation. [XNAnimation Library](http://xnanimation.codeplex.com/)

P.S. You can find a lot of tutorials and libraries for animation if you search "Skinned Model"